# Scanning date using sscanf

Tags: string, matlab, scanf

I have the following data over one year that is structured like so.  This is an example of one instance.  This data is also stored in a text file.

```
1/1/2013  3:00:00 AM
```

How would I read this data? This is what i have so far and i get an error saying:

> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

This is the code I have written:

```
for i = 1:k
    str = dateAndTime{i,1};
    [A, count]=sscanf(str,'%u/%u/%u %u:%u:%*u %*c'); % month day year hour minutes seconds pm/am
    dateNumber(i) = datenum([A(3) A(1) A(2) A(4) A(5) 0 0]); % Y M D H M S PM/AM datenum returns decimal day 
end
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try remove one 0 (to leave only a 6-element vector as input to `datenum`)?

Comment: Does not work. Get an error saying 'Attempted to access A(4); index out of bounds because numel(A)=3.'

Comment: That error is inconsistent with what @seb is asking.  Removing one of the zeroes in your `datenum` argument should **not** change the dimensions of `A`.  You're doing something else that you're not accounting for.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sscanf` statement is slightly incorrect.  When you're reading in the seconds field, you incorrectly placed a `*` when there shouldn't be one.  You'll also want to get rid of the `*` for determining the characters `AM/PM`.  All you really need is the first character `A` or `P`.  The reason why you want to get rid of the `*` is because you want to read one number **per element** in the matrix `A`.

When you do this and when you run `sscanf`, we thus get the following matrix for `A`, using your data in your post as an example:

```
[A, count]=sscanf('1/1/2013  3:00:00 AM','%u/%u/%u %u:%u:%u %c');

A =

       1
       1
    2013
       3
       0
       0
      65
```

As you can see `A(1)` is the month, `A(2)` is the day, `A(3)` is the year, `A(4)` is the hour, `A(5)` is the minute and `A(6)` is the second.  `A(7)` will either be `65` or `80` to denote the character `A` or `P` as these are the ASCII codes for each of the characters.  Therefore, if `A(7) = 80`, we need to add 12 to the hour number to denote that this is in the afternoon.  `datenum` doesn't seem to take a seventh variable to denote whether it's in the morning or afternoon, and so we need to signify this by adding to the hour.

As such, modify your loop so that it looks like this:

```
for i = 1:k
    str = dateAndTime{i,1};
    [A, count]=sscanf(str,'%u/%u/%u %u:%u:%u %c'); % month day year hour minutes seconds pm/am
    if (A(7) == 80) %// Check if it's in the morning or afternoon
        hour = 12;
    else
        hour = 0;
    end
    dateNumber(i) = datenum(A(3),A(1),A(2),A(4)+hour,A(5),A(6)); % Y M D H M S PM/AM datenum returns decimal day 
end
```

To test this, let's see what happens when we make we have the same string, but in both AM and PM:

```
dateAndTime = {'1/1/2013  3:00:00 AM'; '1/1/2013  3:00:00 PM'};
k = numel(dateAndTime);
```

Using the above, we get the following output stored in `dateNumber`:

```
dateNumber =

 735235.13     735235.63
```

---

Make sure you do `format bank` so you can actually see it like this, or else it will print using exponential notation as this is the default representation in MATLAB for any numbers that are sufficiently large.

Comment: I believe i do not need to add the 12 hours because its in 0-23 hours. I used the set of codes you provided without the 12 hours if-else statement and "+hour". 
But i got an error, stating "Attempted to access A(4); index out of bounds because numel(A)=3."

Comment: @user3698120 For me the code works, assuming that the string is of the same format as what you have provided in your post.  If it doesn't work, you're not formatting the inputs properly.  I'm going to leave it here and let you figure it out.  Note that I have made a **reproducible** example and it gives me the proper outputs.  Maybe you should examine your date strings and see if they match up with the format of your post.  Good luck!

Comment: @user3698120: Check how you set dateAndTime, as it looks like `dateAndTime{i,1}` does not expend to what you want.

Comment: @seb - I agree.  OP: Check your cell array and see how it's formatted.  Is each element an **entire** string, or only a subset of an entire string?